# sending parameters to a function according to input

Tags: c, function, input, parameters

I have a simple typedef (typedef int set [4]) and creations of it.
I have a function that gets 3 of this typedef as parameters.

Now, I want the function to be called with parameters according to the input.
For example, if the input is A,D,R (assume those are allready created), so the the function will be called as func(A,D,R).

I have tried using swich to match the char, and then send the apropriate parameter, but it gets too messy, I tried some other thing aswell but I could not relate between the input and the object name.

I write it in C by the way.
Any help would be apreciated

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to do something like: `sscanf("%c%c%c", &c0, &c1, &c2); if (c0 == 'A' && c1 == 'D' && c2 == 'R') func(A, D, R);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pass parameters by name.  Assuming that's the case, two approaches come to mind.

If your set names really are single-character names like `A`, `D`, `R`, etc., you could build an array of `set` pointers indexed by the character:

```
set *sets[128]; // will result in a lot of unused sets, but
                // indexing is fast and dead easy

sets['A'] = &A;
sets['D'] = &D;
sets['R'] = &R;
...
char s1, s2, s3;
scanf( " %c %c %c", &s1, &s2, &s3 );     // Note a complete lack of error checking
func( *sets[s1], *sets[s2], *sets[s3] ); // You *will* want to validate your inputs
```

If you don't want to waste quite as much space, you can do something like

```
set *sets[26]; // just uppercase letters

int base = 'A';
sets['A'-base] = &A;
sets['D'-base] = &D;
sets['R'-base] = &R;
...
scanf( " %c %c %c", &s1, &s2, &s3 );                    // Again, absolutely no error checking
func( *sets[s1-base], *sets[s2-base], *sets[s3-base] ); // You have been warned
```

This assumes that you're using an encoding where all uppercase letters are sequential (ASCII or UTF-8).

If you're being a smart code monkey and using *meaningful* names for your sets, you could use a lookup table indexed by a character *string*, something like the following:

```
set foo, bar, bletch...;

struct lut_entry {
  char *name;
  set *data;
};

struct lut_entry lut[] = { 
  {"foo", &foo}, 
  {"bar", &bar},
  {"bletch", &bletch},
  ...
  { NULL, NULL } // sentinel value
};
```

You could then search this table for each input:

```
set *lookup( const char *name, struct lut_entry *lut )
{
  struct lut_entry *cur = lut;
  while ( cur->name && strcmp( cur->name, name ) )
    cur++;
  return cur->data;
}
```

which you'd call as something like:

```
scanf( "%s %s %s", name1, name2, name3 );

set *s1 = lookup( name1, lut );
set *s2 = lookup( name2, lut );
set *s3 = lookup( name3, lut );

if ( s1 && s2 && s3 )
  func( *s1, *s2, *s3 ); // note dereference operations!
else
  // one or more of name1, name2, and name3 are invalid
  // handle as appropriate
```

Depending on how many sets you're managing and how crucial speed is to this application you might want to look into something a bit more sophisticated than an unordered linear array search, but it won't be worth the effort if it's less than a dozen or so.

Why didn't I just pass the names to `func` and have it do all the lookup work?  You absolutely could do that, but it means `func` would have to share state with its caller through global variables, which I try to avoid whenever I can, and it means `func` *always* has to do the lookup whether you want it to or not.  Better to have `func` receive the sets as-is and have the calling function do the lookup since the calling function knows whether or not its being driven by user input.

Comment: yey it worked :)  thanks for answering so quickly and so detailedly, you guys are the best!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly, you have characters that you want to translate to variables with that name.. That is `'A'` to become `set A`?

Rolling with this assumption, here is a way to do it:

```
#include <assert.h>
set func(set x, set y, set z);

// Global definitions for all set variables.
struct sets {
    set A;
    set B;
    set C;
    ...
    set Z;    
} allSets;

set callFuncForParams(char c1, char c2, char c3)
{
    set *x, *y, *z;

    // Make sure the input is legal
    assert(c1 >= 'A' && c1 <= 'Z');
    assert(c2 >= 'A' && c2 <= 'Z');
    assert(c3 >= 'A' && c3 <= 'Z');

    x = (set *)&allSets + c1 - 'A';
    y = (set *)&allSets + c2 - 'A';
    z = (set *)&allSets + c3 - 'A';

    return func(*x, *y, *z);
}
```

Another approach, especially useful if you don't have all the letters as variables, is to make an array of `struct { char c; set s; }`, and then go through that array to find your variable. You can use macros and the # operator to generate that array.